# C# LIKE query doesn't work

Tags: sql, nhibernate

Could someone help me out? I don't normally work in C#, so my apologies. I have the following query that works, but need to change the store.Zip lookup to a `LIKE` instead of `=`. When I try just changing the `=` to `LIKE` and add `%` after `{0}` it compiles, but doesn't run. The database is Sql Server 2008:

```
public List<Store> DoesStoreExist(string customerNumber, string zipCode) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("SELECT id, Company, CustomerNumber, Name, Address, City, State, Zip, Phone, Latitude, Longitude, NumOfReferrals, IsNashville, PredsPromotionParticipant ");
    sb.Append("FROM dbo.Stores store ");
    sb.AppendFormat("WHERE store.CustomerNumber='{0}' ", customerNumber);
    sb.AppendFormat("AND store.Zip ='{0}' ", zipCode);
    sb.AppendFormat("AND store.Locator=1");

    IQuery query = NHibernateSession.CreateSQLQuery(sb.ToString());
    IList results = query.List();
    List<Store> stores = new List<Store>();
    foreach (object result in results) {
        object[] result_arr = result as object[];
        if (result_arr != null) stores.Add(Store.From(result_arr));
    }
    return stores;

}
```

Even just changing the "=" to "LIKE" causes the query to not return:

```
public List<Store> DoesStoreExist(string customerNumber, string zipCode) 
{        
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("SELECT id, Company, CustomerNumber, Name, Address, City, State, Zip, Phone, Latitude, Longitude, NumOfReferrals, IsNashville, PredsPromotionParticipant ");
        sb.Append("FROM dbo.Stores store ");
        sb.AppendFormat("WHERE store.CustomerNumber='{0}' ", customerNumber);
        sb.AppendFormat("AND store.Zip LIKE '{0}%' ", zipCode);
        sb.AppendFormat("AND store.Locator=1");

    IQuery query = NHibernateSession.CreateSQLQuery(sb.ToString());
    IList results = query.List();
    List<Store> stores = new List<Store>();
    foreach (object result in results) {
        object[] result_arr = result as object[];
        if (result_arr != null) stores.Add(Store.From(result_arr));
    }
    return stores;
}
```

When I run the following against the database directly, it works:

```
SELECT * FROM [StoreDB].[dbo].[Stores]WHERE Zip LIKE '33815%'
```

Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The fact that it doesn't run is an SQL problem, not C# - the query looks fine. I would hazard a guess at the input being wrong and you get no matches from the db.

Comment: What is the error? What is the value of `customerNumber`?

Comment: did you try using %% instead of %?

Comment: I suggest making the percent sign part of your zipCode variable.

Comment: Have you tried `("AND store.Zip LIKE '%{0}%' ", zipCode);`?

Comment: What error do you get when running it? What provider are you using to connect to the SQL Server 2008 database? Can you show your actual code when you tried the LIKE statement?

Comment: Also, I don't see `like` anywhere ?

Comment: What query is being sent to the database?

Comment: Can you please post your query with like ?

Comment: Your code is also vulnerable to SQL injection. Research using parameters.

Comment: Did you notice you don't run any query at all? You build up a stringbuilder then... nothing. The compiler should even complain you don't return anything.

Comment: Sorry, the entire method is posted now

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    public List<Store> DoesStoreExist(string customerNumber, string zipCode)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("SELECT id, Company, CustomerNumber, Name, Address, City, State, Zip, Phone, Latitude, Longitude, NumOfReferrals, IsNashville, PredsPromotionParticipant ");
        sb.Append("FROM dbo.Stores store ");
        sb.AppendFormat("WHERE store.CustomerNumber ='{0}' ", customerNumber);
        sb.AppendFormat("AND store.Zip like '{0}%' ", zipCode);
        sb.AppendFormat("AND store.Locator=1");
    }
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is handle zip+4--sometimes the last four digits aren't in the database.  Thanks!

Comment: Look at my answer, I'm assuming you get the timeout exception from the SQL database. You still haven't mentioned what error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
sb.AppendFormat("AND store.Zip like '{0}%' ", zipCode);

Answer (score 0):

If it times out, then you need to increase the command timeout. Assuming your entity object is called 'db', do this before executing the query in your c# code.

```
db.CommandTimeout = 300;
```

The timeout is in seconds.